# Setting up APK Expansion files for update releases

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I need some clarification on using APK Expansion files.

I have tested and will be releasing my Android app using APK Expansion files for the first time.

My app versionCode is 61
My main expansion file is main.61.com.my.package.obb
There is no patch file.

In planning ahead for my first update with expansion files, I'm a little unclear on the numbering for the expansion files and what I would load to Google Play.

My next releases versionCode will be 62
There will be no changes to the main expansion file, but I need the main file.
Do I use main.61.com.my.package.obb?
There will be a patch file: patch.62.com.my.package.obb.

Any clarification will be most appreciated.

jb

Answer (score 2):

See the clear explanation given in the google docs.

```
<expansion-version>
```

This is an integer that matches the version code of the APK with which the expansion is first associated (it matches the application's android:versionCode value).

"First" is emphasized because although the Developer Console allows you to re-use an uploaded expansion file with a new APK, the expansion file's name does not change—it retains the version applied to it when you first uploaded the file.

You are right there should not be nay change in the file name of the main expansion file.